# DHCPv6 server + client on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dhcp, ipv6

Which IPv6 capable DHCP server and client is best to use on Ubuntu? I can't find a good HOWTO.

ISC DHCP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Use ISC DHCP. Had no problems for years.

Few links for free:

- [Configuration of the ISC DHCP server for IPv6](http://mirrors.bieringer.de/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/hints-daemons-isc-dhcp.html)
- [Dynamic Host Configuration IPv6 Server](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/network_administration_guides/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/hints-daemons-dhcpv6..html)

Comment: These links cover IPv4 only

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the links for IPv6.